# Enable failed/canceled workflow

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, azure-integration-account

[image]Connected Azure api management with logicapp.
By following ms document created workflow as shown

Created business requirements workflow in logicapps by taking when a http request received and http actions by providing apis

Now my workflow is some times success and failed but in run history I want to see only failure or canceled one.

Answer (score 1):

Issue reproduced from my end and able to get expected results by flowing below approach.

- Created logic App and as shown in image in logic App overview run history it is selected All in built so you are seeing all success, failure and cancelled run history.
  [image]
- To view only failure ones, Go to >> logic App overview >> Run history >> select failure/canceled as shown in below image.
  [image]
- I can sell Failed run records after choosing Status as Failed instead of All.

[image]